# Как в python импортировать модуль по объекту-строке?

Tags: python, список, python-2.x, импорт

У меня есть список названий модулей такой как`["module1", "module2", "module3"]` этот список может пополняться. Вопрос: как импортировать модуль название которого совпадает с текстом элемента списка.
Пример:

```
import modules_my[0]
```

есть какие-нибудь рабочие методы?

Comment: см. `importlib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html) (В Py3 у него еще больше всяких функций).

```
import importlib
np = importlib.import_module('numpy')
np.random.random()
>>> 0.10880518874684186
```

Comment: теперь всё работает, очень благодарен